# Flutter breaking after installing Git for Windows (VS Code shows "The Flutter Daemon failed to start" and "flutter doctor" closes CMD window)

Tags: windows, flutter, git, cmd, git-bash

After installing Git for Windows on my Windows 10 machine, I encountered a problem with Flutter. When I launch Visual Studio Code, it displays the error message "The Flutter Daemon failed to start." Additionally, running flutter doctor in the Command Prompt (CMD) automatically closes the CMD window without output. This issue seemed to be resolved when I uninstalled Git Bash, but after reinstalling Git for Windows, the problem reappeared.

However, it is working when I run cmd and vs code as an administrator

Has anyone else experienced a similar issue, and how can I fix Flutter without uninstalling Git for Windows every time? Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue on Windows by running the command `git config --global --add safe.directory '*'` in Git Bash. After that, I restarted my IDE and regular Command Prompt, and now Flutter works without requiring administrator privileges. You can find more details [here](https://codingislove.com/unable-to-find-git-path-flutter/). Happy coding!